# How to access incoming SMS details

Tags: iphone, sms

I'm developing an application to identify incoming messages (SMS) and makes a file (on the iPhone) and write information about the SMS into it.  I've read about a spy-ware that did this [link](http://www.fortiguard.com/encyclopedia/virus/spy_mobilespy!iphoneos.html)

If they have done this, it means it can be done by others. People keep saying "Do it for jailbreak".  My question is is there any way to do this without jail breaking the phone. If no, then is there any tutorial that can guide me through this process on Private APIs.

Comment: You could have edited that question and tried getting some answers.. posting it again is not a way to go...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access incoming SMS in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519252/access-incoming-sms-in-iphone)

Comment: "i already posted a question based on this but not satisfied with answer..." -- posting it again won't change that. You're asking how to make spyware. Very uncool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way to gain access is to jailbreak your iphone. This is however is NOT recommended and is no way endorsed by me and maybe illegal etc

Also only other jailbreak users would be able to use your app.

> I would seriously consider whether
>   this is something you want to do!

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be done with any public APIs.

Comment: I do not want to put my application on app store and I have jailbreak device. How can I intercept SMS on iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Applications have no access to the SMS functionality of the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

we cant access sms from phone